# How to make folders based on the list names and save the list into respective folders?

Tags: r, directory-structure

My example list. So it has like 3 tables. So right now when i save this list into files I can save into individual list. In my list this ID is "`PMC7837979`" for example is unique.The files are saved as PMC7837979.Table1.txt , PMC7837979.Table2.txt etc etc. So all the things are cluttered now.

So right now my list contains as a small subset example 6 unique IDs. Under each ID there are multiple tables. So my objective.

- For each unique ID generate a folder and the save the respective ID inside it such as if "`PMC7837979`" has 3 tables then all the files should be inside the PMC7837979 named folder?

"PMC7837979" "PMC7809753" "PMC7790830" "PMC7797573" "PMC7806552" "PMC7836575"

```
dput(head(my_tables,1))
list(PMC7837979 = list(`Table 1` = structure(list(`Clinical feature` = c("Sex, n, Male/female", 
"Age, yr, Median (range)", "WBC × 109/L, Mean ± SD", 
"Course of CR", "One period of treatment, n", "Two periods of treatment, n", 
"Number of courses of consolidation, Median (range)"), `Intermediate dose group, n = 33` = c("15/18", 
"53 (22–73)", "25.3 ± 42.5", NA, "22", "11", "5 (3–7)"
), `Standard dose group, n = 19` = c("10/9", "56 (26–74)", 
"22.8 ± 36.8", NA, "11", "8", "7 (6–8)"), `P value` = c(".25", 
".23", ".52", NA, ".17", "", ".19")), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), caption = "Clinical data of the 155 patients with acute myeloid leukaemia."), 
    `Table 2` = structure(list(subheading = c("3-year survival", 
    "3-year survival", "3-year survival", "3-year survival", 
    "3-year relapse-free survival", "3-year relapse-free survival", 
    "3-year relapse-free survival", "3-year relapse-free survival"
    ), Variable = c("Age", "Treatment strategy (Standard dose)", 
    "Risk grade", "WBC count", "Age", "Treatment strategy (Standard dose)", 
    "Risk grade", "WBC count"), HR = c(1.012, 2.302, 1.033, 0.891, 
    1.01, 2.23, 0.968, 1.002), `95% CI` = c("0.996–1.071", 
    "1.009–5.255", "0.3291–2.412", "0.997–1.027", "0.973–1.048", 
    "1.055–4.715", "0.362–2.594", "0.987–1.108"), `P value` = c(0.079, 
    0.048, 0.82, 0.126, 0.604, 0.036, 0.949, 0.759)), row.names = c(NA, 
    -8L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), caption = "Multivarivate analysis by Cox Regression for survival and relapse-free of 3 year."), 
    `Table 3` = structure(list(subheading = c("Grade 3-4 hematological toxicity", 
    "Grade 3-4 hematological toxicity", "Grade 3-4 hematological toxicity", 
    "Grade 3-4 hematological toxicity", "Grade 3-4 hematological toxicity", 
    "Grade 3-4 hematological toxicity", "Non-hematological toxicity", 
    "Non-hematological toxicity", "Non-hematological toxicity"
    ), Group = c("Neutrophil recovery time (d), Mean ± SD", 
    "Minimum neutrophil time (d), Mean ± SD", "Duration of neutrophil deficiency (d), Mean ± SD", 
    "Platelet recovery time (d), Mean ± SD", "Minimum platelet time (d), Mean ± SD", 
    "Duration of thrombocytopenia (d), Mean ± SD", "Adverse gastrointestinal reactions, n", 
    "Blood transfusion, n", "Infection occurs, n"), `Intermediate dose group, n = 33` = c("15.5 ± 5.9", 
    "10 ± 5.8", "7.8 ± 10.7", "16 ± 5.3", "10.3 ± 2.2", 
    "9.5 ± 7.5", "31", "24", "25"), `Standard dose group, n = 19` = c("14 ± 2.4", 
    "9 ± 1.9", "7 ± 2", "14.5 ± 1.5", "9.4 ± 1.6", 
    "9 ± 2.1", "16", "11", "14"), `P value` = c(0.16, 0.09, 
    0.9, 0.29, 0.47, 0.36, 0.51, 0.43, 0.87)), row.names = c(NA, 
    -9L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), caption = "Grade 3-4 hematological toxicity and non-hematological toxicity.")))
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is a preliminary base R solution as I cannot get your supplied data to work. Could you shorten your data to make it easier to insert it into R?

Let's say we have the following toy data that mimicks your example.

**Data**

```
df <- data.frame(var1 = c(1, 2), var2 = c(2, 3)) 
IDS <- list(A = list(df, df), B = list(df, df))
IDS 
> IDS
$A
$A[[1]]
  var1 var2
1    1    2
2    2    3

$A[[2]]
  var1 var2
1    1    2
2    2    3


$B
$B[[1]]
  var1 var2
1    1    2
2    2    3

$B[[2]]
  var1 var2
1    1    2
2    2    3
```

Then you can use the *apply family as follows.

**Code**

```
lapply(names(IDS), function(x) {dir.create(x); 
                    sapply(1:length(IDS[[x]]), function(y) {
                      write.table(IDS[[x]][y],  file = paste(x, "/",  paste(x, y, sep = "_"), 
                                                              ".txt", sep = ""))
                    })
})
```

The code creates a folder for every list in your list with `dir.create()` with the name being based on the `names()` of the entire list object. Then it unpacks all `data.frame`s it finds in each list in the respective folders and naming them by means of list and a unique number. Is that what you had in mind?